# OpenCV Java - How to iterate on a 4-dimensional Mat (and work with it)

Tags: java, opencv, caffe, mat

I am trying to do face detection with OpenCV's DNN module with Caffe:

```
Mat faceBlob = Dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0, new Size(300, 300), new 
Scalar(104.0, 177.0, 123.0, 0), false, false, CvType.CV_32F); //Construct blob

detector.setInput(faceBlob); //set the input to network model
Mat output = detector.forward();  //get output
```

Here's the thing: the output is a 1x1x124x7 Mat and I have tried everything for 8 hours now to no result to get to the 124x7 Mat that actually contains useful data. 
I would appreciate any advice on how I can iterate/reference that 124 by 7 matrix inside of the 4-d matix so much! Thanks!

Comment: [take a look here maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27702231/opencv-3d-mat-to-vector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line from here https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d6c/tutorial_dnn_android.html saved my day. Also, thanks mavriksc for his comment.

```
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d6c/tutorial_dnn_android.html
```